# Publishing a Dialogflow agent doesn't update API answers

Tags: php, dialogflow-es

My application, when passing an utterance to my Dialogflow agent, is not returning the up-to-date answers.

I have created a Dialogflow agent that I am accessing through a Google Service account using Google's PHP library.  I have "published" a number of times to the "Web" environment.

I just made a new intent which is matched and answered properly in the Dialogflow UI's test console.  When I type the same utterance into my application, I get a default fallback answer.

Looking on the "History" page at the conversation log, all the utterances are marked as being in the "Draft" environment - even utterances that come via my application.

How do I connect my application to my agent in such a way that it uses the version published to the "Web" environment.

Answer (score -1):

I'm new to DialogueFlow myself, but I'll try to help.
This is where my chatbot lives: http://sidwho.com/ai.html 
Are you trying to do the same? If so, I logged into my https://console.dialogflow.com -> went to "integrations" -> "web demo" -> turned it on (blue) -> copied the iframe code-> pasted it into my website using Dreamweaver.

Comment: I've found that embed code is temporary.  And no, I'm not trying to use the web demo, I'm building my own.